# Correct way of adding additional routes to resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering if there is a more elegant or in any way "correct" way of adding additional routes to resource controller?

For instance I could have `UsersController` and route it with

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

And it will route methods according to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers)

But if for any reason I wanted to add a method outside of this scope I could do something like

```
Route::get('users/token', 'UserController@authToken');
```

So obviously this works, but is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no better way to do that. Since `::controller` was deprecated, you should explicitly declare each additional route.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why ::controller got deprecated as it seemed like great option to route everything and imply http method with controller method name `getUser` => `GET /user`

Comment: The idea was that explicit routes are better than implicit ones.